# How to execlude same month and year in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, exclude-constraint

short code

```sql
drop table if exists x;
create temp table x(
d date,
  exclude using gist (extract(month from d) with =,
                      extract(year from d) with =)
);
```

how to make this possible
`CREATE EXTENSION if not exists btree_gist;` -- i also tried

I don't want overlapping month and year

Comment: You code working as intended. What's the issue? You cannot install extension?

Comment: it seemed i had a typing issue here or there

Comment: Hmm, a regular unique index should be sufficient: `create unique index on x ( extract(year from d), extract(month from d) ) ;`

Comment: @RamiJamleh What's the error message?

Comment: no errors now it was a datatype thing could you please show me inline exculode clause with constraint name

Comment: @RamiJamleh What's a "datatype thing"?

Comment: CREATE EXTENSION if not exists btree_gist this ext deals with numbers to work with btree now it works just forget it